# Application Name remain empty for virtual directory in IIS 6 using C#

Tags: c#, iis-6, virtual-directory

I am creating virtual directory in IIS 6 using C#.

I am able to create the virtual directory but the 'Application Name' field remains empty.

[image]

Here's the code I am using

> DirectoryEntry iisRoot = new
>   DirectoryEntry("IIS://" +
>   Environment.MachineName + "/W3SVC");
>
> string webName = "1";
>
> string virdir = "TestApp1";
>
> string installpath = @"C:\MyWeb\Application\";
>
> ```
>         try
>         {
>             string iisPath = string.Format("IIS://{0}/W3SVC/{1}/Root", Environment.MachineName, webName);
>             Console.WriteLine(iisPath);
>             iisRoot = new DirectoryEntry(iisPath);
>
>             DirectoryEntry vdir = iisRoot.Children.Add(virdir, iisRoot.SchemaClassName);
>
>             vdir.Properties["Path"][0] = installpath;
>             vdir.Properties["AppFriendlyName"][0] = virdir;
>             vdir.Properties["EnableDefaultDoc"][0] = true;
>             vdir.Properties["DefaultDoc"][0] = "Login.aspx,default.htm,default.aspx,default.asp";
>             vdir.Properties["AspEnableParentPaths"][0] = true;
>             vdir.CommitChanges();
>             vdir.Invoke("AppCreate", true);
>         }
>         catch (Exception e)
>         {
>             Console.Write(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
>         }
> ```

I have used 'AppFriendlyName' property but still it does not show up in virtual directory properties.

Comment: Can you obtain the `DirectoryEntry` of a *working* app and inspect the properties?

Comment: I have tried to access the properties and got 'AppFriendlyName' as blank(empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

The 'AppFriendlyName' property must nbe set after the vdir.CommitChanges();

so the code should be

```
DirectoryEntry iisRoot = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + Environment.MachineName + "/W3SVC");

string webName = "1";

string virdir = "TestApp1";

string installpath = @"C:\MyWeb\Application\";

        try
        {
            string iisPath = string.Format("IIS://{0}/W3SVC/{1}/Root", Environment.MachineName, webName);
            Console.WriteLine(iisPath);
            iisRoot = new DirectoryEntry(iisPath);

            DirectoryEntry vdir = iisRoot.Children.Add(virdir, iisRoot.SchemaClassName);

            vdir.Properties["Path"][0] = installpath;
            vdir.Properties["EnableDefaultDoc"][0] = true;
            vdir.Properties["DefaultDoc"][0] = "Login.aspx,default.htm,default.aspx,default.asp";
            vdir.Properties["AspEnableParentPaths"][0] = true;
            vdir.CommitChanges();
            vdir.Invoke("AppCreate", true);
            vdir.Properties["AppFriendlyName"][0] = virdir;
            vdir.CommitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

AppFriendlyName is the property to be set as per [IIS 6 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525425%28VS.90%29.aspx). Perhaps, you can try `vdir.Properties["AppFriendlyName"].Value = "Some Name";`.

Comment: I tried the same but no success. Anyways finally doing some testing and tweaks I got the answer.

Comment: @Sunil, why don't you share the same with rest of us - may help somebody sometime!

Comment: Yes I have posted the answer. But I don't know why is it so